# Zypp curl error during installing OpenSUSE 13.1

Tags: opensuse, autoyast

I have error during automatic install OpenSuse with AutoYAST.
First stage completes successfully.
But when server restarts I get error when autorefreshing repos.

In y2log error

`zypp error MediaCurl.cc(doGetFileCOpyFile): Download (curl) error for 'http://download.opensuse.org/...`

But internet settings are working right after installing. What's wrong?